# Angular: @Output EventEmitter subscription

Tags: angular, typescript

I've coded a directive with an `@Output EventEmitter` property:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ifValid]'
})
export class SubmitValidationDirective {

    @Output('ifValid') valid = new EventEmitter<void>();

    constructor(
        private formRef: NgForm
    ) {}

    @HostListener('click')
    handleClick() {
        this.emitIfValid();
    }

    private emitIfValid() {
        if (this.formRef.valid) {
           this.valid.emit();
        }
    }

}
```

So, I'm using this like:

```
<button (ifValid)="save()">
```

So then, into my component:

```
private save() {
    this.service.push(this.user, this.toCreate)
       .pipe(
           take(1)
       )
       .subscribe();
}
```

Manual subscription is noising me.

I want that when `ifValid` raises, add this operator-like `switchMap(() => this.service.push(...))`.

I would like to know if it's possible to subscribe to `ifValid` out of html. I mean, Could I subscribe to `ifValid` inside of my component?

I hope I've explained so well.

Comment: You can get instance of your directive through ViewChild decorator. It should be enough to subscribe to any observable. But you have to unsubscribe yourself in this case. Note that using output event Angular will take of it itself

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@ViewChield(SubmitValidationDirective) component;` in your component and afterwards you can use

```
this.component.valid.subscribe(() => {this.service.push(this.user, this.toCreate)
       .pipe(
           take(1)
       )
       .subscribe();
});
```

But you will have to `unsubscribe()` in for example your `ngOnDestroy`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, For that we need to create a one service and on that service we declare the `@Output`

**SharedService**

```
@Output('ifValid') valid = new EventEmitter<void>();
```

**componentOne**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.sharedService.valid.subscribe(resp => {
     this.save()
});
}

private save() {
    this.service.push(this.user, this.toCreate)
       .pipe(
           take(1)
       )
       .subscribe();
}
```

**Directive or Component**

```
import { SharedService } from 'Sharedservice';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ifValid]'
})
export class SubmitValidationDirective {
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }
    @Output('ifValid') valid = new EventEmitter<void>();

    constructor(
        private formRef: NgForm
    ) {}

    @HostListener('click')
    handleClick() {
        this.emitIfValid();
    }

    private emitIfValid() {
        if (this.formRef.valid) {
          this.sharedService.valid.emit(null);
        }
    }

}
```